# Bootstrap 4 – Text/Icon on <progress> element

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-4

I am trying to overlay an icon on a progress bar in the Bootstrap 4 alpha.

```
<progress class="progress progress-primary" value="100" max="100">
  <i class="fa fa-check-circle-o"></i>
</progress>
```

It should look like the following (roughly):

[image: Desired Result]

Instead, I end up with the following:

[image: Actual Result]

Unfortunately, no combination of `appearance:initial;` and `!important` tags are doing the trick.

What am I missing that is causing the text within the `<progress>` element to not show?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the latest version of Bootstrap 4, `alpha-6`, this issue isn't a problem anymore:

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0-alpha.6/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<div class="progress">
  <div class="progress-bar" role="progressbar" style="width: 25%;" aria-valuenow="25" aria-valuemin="0" aria-valuemax="100">25%</div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

Move the icon outside the progress element and use `position:relative`..

```
<progress class="progress" value="10" max="100"></progress>
<i class="fa fa-check-circle-o"></i>

.fa {
    position: relative;
    z-index: 2;
    top: -35px;
    left: 50%;
}
```

http://www.codeply.com/go/gl3DnWcPKu